# Draw From Old Canvas - Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm making an App that needs to be able to draw new graphics on top of the last set.

This is my current onDraw() method -

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    if(points.size() > 0) {
        //do some stuff here - this is all working ok
        canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, linePaint);
    }   
}
```

Basically, I need to draw the new graphics as a layer on top of the last, so what I'm looking for is a way to carry the image of the last canvas to the current.

I have tried to figure it out myself using the canvas.setBitmap() method but it acts very funny.

Any help appreciated :)

P.S if it's needed, the the class extends `SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`

Edit: This is what I have tried in the onDraw() method but it just force closes

```
if(bitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself :)

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

if(bitmap != null && canvas != null) { 
    canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, linePaint);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, linePaint);  
}
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Works exactly as intended, it creates the effect of drawing on top of the old canvas continuously

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the previous image persistently onto a ArrayList, and during ondraw, loop through the ArrayList to redraw all items.

something like this:

```
for (Graphic graphic : _graphics) {
    bitmap = graphic.getBitmap();
    coords = graphic.getCoordinates();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can create a bitmap image of the canvas and then just draw that next time onDraw() is called? There will a LOT of lines drawn every frame and this way I think is very processor comsuming