# Android ImageView How to draw path

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

I have an ImageView with a background image. The ImageView is sized programmatically as a percentage of the screen. The view is in a RelativeLayout and it is at the center of it. What I want is to make it drawable. I want to be able to draw in it with my finger (just like we were drawing nonsense in paint as we were kids). Also when I'm moving my finger I want the path to be drawn immediately. Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some very good references to drawing apps, found with a small amount of Googling:

Simple App to get a good wet finger / easy to implement:
http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/11/simple-drawing-example-in-android.html

More Complicated, but very thorough explanation:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-touch-interaction--mobile-19202

Neither are using a ImageView, but I'm sure you could accommodate switching View Types

Answer (score 1):

Just take GestureOverlayView and set your image as background of this OverlayView.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
           android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="5"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
           android:fadeEnabled="false"
           android:gestureColor="@color/black"
           android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
           android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
       </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

and function to save image from GestureOverlayView.

```
try {
          GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);
            gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());
           File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                   + File.separator + "signature.png");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
           os = new FileOutputStream(f);
           //compress to specified format (PNG), quality - which is ignored for PNG, and out stream
           bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
          os.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("Gestures", e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

follow this [Example](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-gestureoverlayview-to-capture-a-quick-signature-or-drawing/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to override the ImageView's `onTouchEvent` and `onDraw` calls. Get the user's touch position in `onTouchEvent` and draw to the `ImageView`'s `canvas`.
See example here - 
[paint canvas android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895642/paint-canvas-android)